# How to Create Datavisual Shapes for R Package

Tags: r, package, data-visualization, shapes

How do I create datavisual shapes for R package.

Just like there are heatmaps, bar charts, pie charts, etc.

For instance, I wish to create a car as a datavisual shape in R. Perhaps use it as a map. And give users the options to label the components

What do I search in google to create such a thing?

For instance I would like R (I'm used to R) to generate a user-input program where

1. `product-to-repair-tires` will point to **tires**
2. `tire-pressure` will point to each of the 4 **tires**
3. `number-of-oil-changes` will point to **oil tank**
4. `type-of-fuel` (variables `gasoline`,`diesel`,`liquified petroleum`,etc) will point to **fuel tank**.

I want this custom visual to

1. Have words and/or icons pointing to it
2. Be treated as a map. For instance, tires passed inspection by 80%, brake pads passed by 20% (hence need a replacement), windshield wipers are 100% perfect, bumper is can widthstand impact 30% (need replacement)
3. Can be used to demonstrate car health over time. We can include this in a report like Carfax that show when the Car was manufactured to possible accidents, defects as it passed owners.

In other words, custom visual should tell the life and health of a car in few words.

[image]

Comment: Do you wish to do this within a specific framework like ggplot or grid? It is feasible by creating a geom within ggplot, but to make it work as a malleable data visualisation target would be a major project. I think you need to give a more concrete example of what you're trying to do. Although it's a good question, and an interesting one, it's just too broad for Stack Overflow as it stands.

Comment: I have seen visuals that fill up an image of a person, for example to demonstrate different levels of response by gender. That might help you google an example.

Comment: I’ve seen something similar done in R, but getting the right search term is tricky. https://images.app.goo.gl/tu1yxFpffQSKKA3Q7

Comment: Aha! Check this out https://www.listendata.com/2019/06/create-infographics-with-r.html search terms : r infographic

Comment: I updated question, please reply.

Comment: @AllanCameron please see updated answer

Comment: @MarkNealI shall google this also

Comment: @Marium I guessed that was what you meant. I do think it would be pretty cool, but it's more like a whole project that would take a couple of weeks and a few hundred lines of code, rather than a programming _problem_ that can be solved on Stack Overflow. That is, unless you are asking for library recommendations, which is also off topic. For what it's worth, I don't know of any packages that will do this directly, but it is definitely possible in R using various graphic packages like grid, ggplot2 and magick. It would be very worthwhile to pursue writing it as a package.